# Gradle ignores transitive dependencies

Tags: gradle, gradlefx

I'm trying to use a Flex library (SWC) which defines a few dependencies within it's POM. I was hoping that Gradle would automatically provide those transitive depencencies. However, `gradle dependencies` shows just the one dependency that has been added manually.

```
merged
\--- com.example:flex-core:1.0.0
```

The POM file of the library contains the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>flex-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>swc</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.as3commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>as3commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.6</version>
      <type>swc</type>
      <scope>external</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.as3commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>as3commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <type>swc</type>
      <scope>external</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.as3commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>as3commons-reflect</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <type>swc</type>
      <scope>external</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've added the following dependency in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    merged 'com.example:flex-core:1.0.0@swc'
}
```

Why is Gradle ignoring the dependencies from the POM? Is it because of the "external" scope?
Is it possible to get those dependencies without adding them manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the [artifact only notation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#artifactOnly) when declaring your dependency (`@scw`). This means Gradle will only retrieve the artifact itself but not use the transitive dependencies from the POM.

Try this instead:

```
dependencies {
    merged 'com.example:core:1.0.0'
}
```

Shouldn't the name be `flex-core`? At least that's what the POM says above.

Comment: I've updated my question and fixed the artifact names. Thanks for pointing out.